# Proving that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. Also find the kernel and image of $\phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism, image-processing

Question: Let $\phi$ : $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be given by $\phi (n)$=$7n$.
 Prove that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism. Find the kernel and image of $\phi$
Definition of homomorphism: Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two groups. Then $\phi$ : $G_1 \to G_2$ is called a homomorphism iff $\forall$ $a,b \in G_1$. So $\phi (ab)$= $\phi (a)$$\phi (b)$
Definition of kernel: If $\phi$ : $G_1 \to G_2$ is a homomorphism
Then {$g \in G_1$ : $\phi (G_1)$=$e_2$} is called the kernel of $\phi$ denoted by ker $\phi$
Alternate definition of kernel of $\phi$ : Ker $\phi$ :={$x\in G_1 : \phi (x)$=$e_2$} note: $\phi$$^{-1}(e_2)$ is also included. 
Here is my attempt:
 $\phi (n)$=$7n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$
So $\phi$ is onto
 $\phi(n_1)$+$\phi(n_2)$=$\phi(n_1 + n_2)$
$\qquad\qquad\quad$=$\phi(n_1)$+$\phi(n_2)$
$\qquad\qquad\quad$=$7n_1$+$7n_2$
$\qquad\qquad\quad$=$7(n_1+n_2)$
 $\phi(n_1+n_2)$=$7(n_1+n_2)$
LHS=RHS (lefthand side is equal to right hand side)
 therefore, $\phi$ is $1$- $1$ 
 I am struggling to find the kernel and image of $\phi$.
I need help. Also you can check the work I have done so far if I made some errors

Comment: Your proof for the fact that $\phi$ is a homomorphism is at least confusing. You have to prove that $\phi(n_1+n_2) = \phi(n_1) + \phi(n_2)$.

Comment: $\phi$ is not onto.  Also, it seems from what you've written that you don't know what 1-1 and onto mean.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I did prove $\phi(n_1 + n_2)$=$\phi(n_1)$+$\phi(n_2)$. Hence, LHS=RHS

Comment: There are already comments and answers regarding homomorphism.  The kernel is given by $$Ker \phi=\{n\in\Bbb Z:\phi(n)=0\}=\{n\in\Bbb Z:7n=0\}=\{0\}$$ and $$Im \phi=\{f(n):n\in\Bbb Z\}=\{7n:n\in\Bbb Z\}=\{\dots,-14,-7,0,7,14,\dots\}=7\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: @behold: No,you did not! Why don'T you trust in more experienced people than yourself?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I see where my mistake was at but my concept is good. Thanks for pointing that out for me

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp my bad for coming off as arrogant but I wholeheartedly thought my proof was correct. Again thanks for letting me know my error.The guy below in the answer explained why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homomorphism proof as it currently stands is incorrect.

You have:

> \begin{align*}
> \phi(n_1)+\phi(n_2) & \color{red}{=} \phi(n_1+n_2) \\
> & \color{red}{=} \phi(n_1)+\phi(n_2) \\
> & = 7n_1+7n_2 \\
> & = 7(n_1+n_2)
> \end{align*}

You have the important elements here, but they're arranged in a confusing way, that I would consider incorrect.
Specifically, the red equalities above are incorrect.

If you have a group $(G,+)$, and another group $(H,\oplus)$, a group homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$ is a function $\phi$ such that, for all $x,y\in G$:
$$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x)\oplus\phi(y)$$
Note that there are different operations "inside" $\phi$'s brackets vs outside of them.
This is because the elements $x,y\in G$ (so are combined using $G$'s operation), but $\phi(x),\phi(y)\in H$ (so are combined using $H$'s operation).

A homomorphism is a function that satisfies the above.
So, to prove something is a homomorphism, you need to prove that it always satisfies that equation.

Let $\phi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ be defined by $x\mapsto 7x$.
Then, we have that $\phi(x+y) = 7(x+y)$.
We also have that $\phi(x)+\phi(y) = 7x+7y$.
Can we show that these expressions are equal?  If we can, then $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Showing they're equal isn't too bad, what you do is say that:
$$\phi(x+y) = 7(x+y) \color{red}{=} 7x+7y = \phi(x)+\phi(y)$$
Everything here I've written is just "writing what $\phi(x)$ means" besides the equality in red, which using distributivity of addition in $\mathbb Z$.
But, what we've done here is start with $\phi(x+y)$, and show how that must be equal to $\phi(x)+\phi(y)$, so $\phi$ must be a homomorphism.

Comment: I see. I should have stopped after the LHS was done and did the RHS separately

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $\phi$ is a homomorphism is correct. However, be careful. You said "$\phi$ is 1-1 or a homomorphism." These are not equivalent concepts. 1-1 means that $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ implies $x = y$, i.e. $\phi$ never maps two different elements to the same image.

The kernel is the set $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\phi(n) = 0$. If $7n = 0$, then what is $n$?

The image is the set of all images. What integers can be written in the form $7n$?

Comment: OP also wrote that $\phi$ is onto (i.e., surjective) which is definitely not the case.